# onLocationChanged Called Twice on every Interval

Tags: android, geolocation

I am writing a location based android application in which i am applying a location listener to capture GPS Co-ordinates, Speed and distance covered. The problem is my "onLocationChanged" callback function is called twice on every interval, causing to add up values 2 times instead of 1. Here is my code for onLocationChanged:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

/*    currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    driverLoc.setDriver_latitude(currentLatitude);
    driverLoc.setDriver_longitude(currentLongitude);

    Toast.makeText(this, currentLatitude + " WORKS " + currentLongitude + "" + (location.getSpeed() * 3.6f), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
*/
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    driverLoc.setDriver_latitude(latitude);
    driverLoc.setDriver_longitude(longitude);

    long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    //Toast.makeText(JourneyStartActivity.this, "Elapsed milliseconds: " + (elapsedMillis/1000),
    //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    long Milis = previousMiliSecs;

    previousMiliSecs = elapsedMillis;

    int hours = (int) (elapsedMillis / 3600000);
    int minutes = (int) (elapsedMillis - hours * 3600000) / 60000;

    long secs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((previousMiliSecs - Milis));

    long currentMilis = previousMiliSecs - Milis;

    if( location.getAccuracy() <=10  && (previousMiliSecs - Milis) >= 10000) {

        Location temp = mCurrentLocation;

        mCurrentLocation = location;

        float[] fArr;
        fArr = new float[3];

        double distance = mCurrentLocation.distanceTo(temp);

        //location.distanceBetween(temp.getLatitude(), temp.getLongitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), fArr);

        //double distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(temp.getLatitude(), temp.getLongitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
        //double distance = fArr[0];

        float journeySpeed = (location.getSpeed() * 3.6f);
       //float journeySpeed = (float) ((distance / 10.0f) * 3.6f);
        //journeySpeed *= 3.6f;

        if (GPSTracker.inJourney) {
            journey.setTotalDistanceCovered(distance);
            journey.setJourneySpeedIntervals(journeySpeed);
        }
/*
    TextView txt = (TextView) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.textView38);
    txt.setText(String.valueOf(journey.getTotalDistanceCovered()));
*/
        //Log.e("Home GPS Update","Lat: " + latitude + " Long: " + longitude + " Speed: " + journeySpeed + " Distance: " + journey.getTotalDistanceCovered());
        Log.e("Home GPS Update", "Lat: " + latitude + " Long: " + longitude + " Speed: " + journeySpeed + " Distance: " + journey.getTotalDistanceCovered() + " Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy() + " Seconds: " + secs);
    }
}
```

Please help me out here as i am stuck on it since last 3 days...

Here is my code That is setting up the Google API Client:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1 * 10000);        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1 * 10000); // 10 second, in milliseconds

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } else {
        //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        driverLoc.setDriverLocation(location);

        driverLoc.setDriver_latitude(currentLatitude);
        driverLoc.setDriver_longitude(currentLongitude);

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude: "+driverLoc.getDriver_latitude() + " Longitude: "+driverLoc.getDriver_longitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


10-31 15:38:07.854 21996-21996/amidtech.android.optimusdrive E/Home GPS Update: Lat: 24.833515 Long: 67.0378417 Speed: 0.0 Distance: 0.0 Accuracy: 4.8 Seconds: 14
10-31 15:38:07.855 21996-21996/amidtech.android.optimusdrive E/Home GPS Update: Lat: 24.833515 Long: 67.0378417 Speed: 0.0 Distance: 0.0 Accuracy: 4.8 Seconds: 14
10-31 15:38:17.856 21996-21996/amidtech.android.optimusdrive E/Home GPS Update: Lat: 24.833515 Long: 67.0378417 Speed: 0.0 Distance: 0.0 Accuracy: 4.8 Seconds: 10
10-31 15:38:17.858 21996-21996/amidtech.android.optimusdrive E/Home GPS Update: Lat: 24.833515 Long: 67.0378417 Speed: 0.0 Distance: 0.0 Accuracy: 4.8 Seconds: 10
10-31 15:38:32.853 21996-21996/amidtech.android.optimusdrive E/Home GPS Update: Lat: 24.833515 Long: 67.0378417 Speed: 0.0 Distance: 0.0 Accuracy: 4.9 Seconds: 14
10-31 15:38:32.854 21996-21996/amidtech.android.optimusdrive E/Home GPS Update: Lat: 24.833515 Long: 67.0378417 Speed: 0.0 Distance: 0.0 Accuracy: 4.9 Seconds: 14
```

Comment: If this is called twice, maybe show the code outside this one. You know, the one that is causing this to be called

Comment: sorry i couldn't get you...
Are you referring to other location functions?

Comment: You are showing the code that is called but you don't show how you set it up to be called. This code doesn't call itself. It doesn't relate to the problem at all.

Comment: i have added the code

Answer (score 1):

Check if you registered the same callback twice, maybe that is the issue.
You adding the same listener twice:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } else { ...
```

Location manager has no cached value and returns null first time. At this point you register the same listener again. You should ignore first null value

Comment: How do i check that?

Comment: You register listener first time, and then, if response is null, register it second time.

Comment: So which one should i remove?

Comment: Can you please give me the right code? Its gonna be a big help for me...

Comment: if (location != null) {
        //If everything went fine lets get latitude and longitude
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        driverLoc.setDriverLocation(location);

        driverLoc.setDriver_latitude(currentLatitude);
        driverLoc.setDriver_longitude(currentLongitude);
    }